# Amazon Redshift: Insert data into table from S3 using Java API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I currently have a file in S3. I would like to issue commands using the Java AWS SDK, to take this data and place it into a RedShift table. If the table does not exist I would like to also create the table. I have been unable to find any clear examples on how to do this so I am wondering if I am going about it the wrong way? Should I be using standard postgres java connectors instead of the AWS SDK?

Comment: Connect (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-in-code.html#connecting-in-code-java) and submit your CREATE TABLE and COPY commands

Comment: Did you manage to get this working ? do you have any blog post or anything related to how this is done ? tx

Comment: The correct way is using a jdbc driver and treating redshift as a psql database. Here is an example I posted for a ruby programmer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438238/how-to-use-ruby-to-write-individual-records-to-a-redshift-database/24443358#24443358

Comment: for my own learning, why did you decide to go from: `S3 -> Redshift` instead of `S3 -> Kinesis -> Redshift`?

Comment: Kinesis is not a bridge between S3 and Redshift. Kinesis is an endpoint you would stream data to... process it.. and place that process data into S3 and/or Redshift

Comment: Do you know how to batch copy data from Kinesis to Redshift?

Comment: When I worked with Kinesis I had to move the Data to s3, and then issue queries to do loads from S3. I HAD to do this because I had to parse my data before moving to redshift. This was when Kinesis first came out, not sure if they have any better options now.

Comment: Also this was because at the Redshift was not "good" at single line loads. For example loading 10,000 lines one at a time with a psql insert command would take much longer than loading one file from s3 with 10,000 lines

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Connect (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-in-code.html#connecting-in-code-java) and submit your CREATE TABLE and COPY commands

Comment: It seems like one of the nice utilities of stackoverflow is to rephrase the true utility/application of a documented featured and then provide a link to the documentation.  It would have taken me a while to find these docs just on the AWS site.

Answer (score 2):

Guys answer serves most of purpose.

I would like to post a working java JDBC code that does exactly Copy from S3 to Redshift table. I hope it will help others.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

public class RedShiftJDBC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            //Even postgresql driver will work too. You need to make sure to choose postgresql url instead of redshift.
            //Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            //Make sure to choose appropriate Redshift Jdbc driver and its jar in classpath
            Class.forName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver");
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("user", "username***");
            props.setProperty("password", "password****");

            System.out.println("\n\nconnecting to database...\n\n");
            //In case you are using postgreSQL jdbc driver.
            //conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://********8-your-to-redshift.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/example-database", props);

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:redshift://********url-to-redshift.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/example-database", props);

            System.out.println("\n\nConnection made!\n\n");

            statement = conn.createStatement();

            String command = "COPY my_table from 's3://path/to/csv/example.csv' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=******;aws_secret_access_key=********' CSV DELIMITER ',' ignoreheader 1";

            System.out.println("\n\nExecuting...\n\n");

            statement.executeUpdate(command);
            //you must need to commit, if you realy want to have data saved, otherwise it will not appear if you query from other session.
            conn.commit();
            System.out.println("\n\nThats all copy using simple JDBC.\n\n");
            statement.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you provision the example-database db in redshift? And how did you create user/pwd ?

Comment: @RoyalTiger We have had connection allowed from one EC2 instance to Resdshift, from that instance we could connect to redshift using psql terminals using root account.  Once done, everything else is just matter of finding SQL and executing.

Comment: Sure and I believe we need to create a db using some script before we try to connect to redshift, isn't it?